# Alternative to add a ServiceLocator instead of App.cs

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvm-light

In my Xamarin Forms project i have following architecture:

A portable project which handle common gui stuff and is inherited by each mobile platform project.

Portable Common project which handles all logic stuff and is inherited by each mobile platform project.

I'm planning to use MVVM Light libraries and SimpleIOC.

Now to the question, in my portable project with common gui stuff i can add a servicelocator (to handle all the viewmodels) to App.cs so that's fine. 
But how can i add it to the common project, to handle services and other logic stuff ?

Answer (score 0):

You won't need an instance of ServiceLocator in every library.

Let's say you got a class `LibraryDependency` in your library and register it to a `ServiceLocator` in the library, your **main** `ServiceLocator` can't resolve the dependency if you add it to a ViewModel contructor.

Just register all desired dependencies to the `SimpleIoC` container in your (executable) main project.